# Word meaning "not preferred" - not antonym

Tags: single-word-requests

I wish to distinguish between items that are preferred and items that are good, but not necessarily preferred. Is there a word to describe the latter?

Comment: Another possibility (which no one else has suggested) is _fallback_, which can refer to a plan or option that is acceptable, though not the first choice, and can be adopted if the preferred choice is unavailable or unworkable for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with "[acceptable](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/acceptable)".

> good enough to be used for a particular purpose or to be considered satisfactory

So, a sentence might read:

> The preferred option is "Solution A" but "Solution B" is *acceptable*.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a suggestion--**suboptimal**. From **Collins**:

**suboptimal** (sʌbˈɒptɪməl)  or suboptimum (sʌbˈɒptɪməm)

adjective   not as good as possible, not quite optimal

Crossword puzzle bloggers reviewing puzzles that could be better often say that the puzzle contains **suboptimal fill**.

Comment: Ah, Rex Parker... One of his favorite complaints.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "tolerable."

"I'd prefer X, but Y is tolerable."